# Application's update feature use case

Tags: uml, use-case

help me to describe the use case update feature in an application. For example, the actor  run the update feature on system/application and then the system will send request/interact with a website who provide the data.
I hope u can give an example image that describes the use case.
thx

Comment: homework? Either way, you need to provide a better description.  "Update Feature" is too generic.  Who's the user?  What are they trying to achieve?  Would expect UC to be named from the problem domain: "Buy a Book", "Submit a Story" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic Use Case should describe the "Update [Entity]" feature, one Actor(Stick Figure) and one Use Case (Oval). The text for the use case should describe the steps in the update including the request/interact step. I would normally use an activity diagram to visualize the flow of the steps, and keep the use case diagram simple.